# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(java.util.function.Function

Tags: java, maven, mobile, appium

I'm new to Appium with Java automation and my tests seem to have started failing after adding the maven dependencies org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal and org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch. Here is a part of the code https://imgur.com/Juy8e

I'm using Selenium 4.1.3

```
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(java.util.function.Function, java.util.function.Function)'

    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.makeW3CSafe(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.<init>(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:54)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:116)
    at com.example.Tests.BaseClass.setup(BaseClass.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:645)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)

Test ignored.
```

I traced the error to AppiunNewSessionCommandPayload. Here is the code snippet Rahttps://imgur.com/a/2QWgMRC

Comment: Something was compiled against a version of a library with that method in it, but the environment you provide doesn’t have it.  Either you need another library or you have an incorrect version of what you have now.

Comment: Yes, its just that I'm not sure where to look or which library is out of date/incompatible? The error log just say that NoSuchMethod and the weird part is it is failing in this part 

URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"); 
driver = new AndroidDriver(url, caps);

It is part of my setup method.

Comment: Jas did you find the problem? Can you please share the solution? Thx